# Write $a$ as a function of $n$ when $\sum_{i=1}^{n} (i + a)^{-1} = 1$

Tags: calculus, integration, summation, approximation

Is there a good integral estimation technique I can apply here? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\int_a^{a+n}\frac 1{x+1}dx<\sum_{i=1}^n\frac 1{a+i}=1<\int_a^{a+n}\frac 1{x}dx\\
\biggl[\ln(x+1)\biggr]_a^{n+a}<1<\biggl[\ln (x)\biggr]_a^{a+n}\\
\ln\frac{a+n+1}{a+1}<1<\ln \frac{a+n}a\\
\ln\left(1+\frac n{a+1}\right)<1<\ln\left(1+\frac na\right)\\
1+\frac n{a+1}<e<1+\frac na\\
\qquad \quad a<\frac n{e-1}<a+1\\
\qquad\blacksquare$$

Comment: I also need to see how this behaves as $n \to \infty$. Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean? The method provides an estimate of $a$ within a range of $1$ for any given $n$, and this range doesn't get any tighter as $n$ increases.

Comment: Sorry different question.